# How do I prove that a definition of an ordered pair does not satisfy the required property?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

It is to my knowledge that any definition of an ordered pair, (a, b), must satisfy this condition:

$\quad (a,b) = (c, d) \iff a = c \land b = d$

However, I chanced upon this definition of an ordered pair:

$\quad (a, b) = \{a, \{b\}\}$

which I know does not satisfy the condition. However, how do I prove this formally?

Comment: You give specific examples of sets $a,b,c,d$ for which either $a\neq c$ or $b\neq d$, yet $\{a,\{b\}\}=\{c,\{d\}\}$. If you “know” it doesn’t satisfy the condition, that must be because you have an example showing it doesn’t. Right?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks! I figured it out.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question if you have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prove false a statement of the form “for all $a,b$, $P(a,b)$”, you just need to provide a counterexample.

In your case the statement is

> for all $a,b$, if $(a,b)=(c,d)$, then $a=c$ and $b=d$

so you need to find $a,b,c,d$ such that $\{a,\{b\}\}=\{c,\{d\}\}$, but with $a\ne c$ or $b\ne d$.

If we want the statement to be false, we can try to make $b\ne d$, say $b=0$ and $d=1$. Now we want to find $a$ and $c$ so that
$$
\{a,\{0\}\}=\{c,\{1\}\}
$$
and taking $a=\{1\}$, $c=\{0\}$ ends the search.

Answer (score 2):

I'm rather new to proofs, so correct me if something goes wrong somewhere and tell me if anything needs fixing.

$$\quad (a, b) = (c, d) \iff a = c \land b = d$$
$$\quad assume \space (a, b) = (c, d)$$
$$\quad (a, b) = (c, d) \implies \{a, \{b\}\} = \{c,\{d\}\}$$
$$\quad suppose \space a = \{d\} \space \land \space c = \{b\}$$
$$\quad \{\{d\},\{b\}\} = \{\{b\},\{d\}\}$$
$$\quad let \space b = 3 \space and \space d = 5, \space then \space b \neq d \space and \space a \neq c \space but \space \{\{5\}, \{3\}\} = \{\{3\},\{5\}\}$$
$$which \space does \space not \space satisfy \space the \space property.$$

Comment: I would suggest picking a **specific** $d$ and $b$ that are different (you never assumed $b\neq d$, so for all you know, $a=c$!), and then explicitly show that the two sets are different.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Could I, say, suppose that $a = \{d\} \ \land \ c = \{b\} \ \land \ a \neq c$? Would that fix the problem?

Comment: No, you don’t get to *suppose* they are different. Either they are or they are not. Choose **specific** $b$ and $d$ that are *explicitly* different. You only need to give one instance of the definition not having the property, so you just give one instance, not a generic one. To prove the product of two primes is not always odd I just need to say “Take 2 and 3; they are both primes and their product is 6, which is even.” I don’t need to say “take $p$ and $q$, and assume $p$ and $q$ do this or that”. Just *exhibit* an explicit example.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin does the latest edit work? Thanks for all the help by the way.

Comment: It does work, but it would be better rephrased by first selecting $b$, $d$, $a$, and $c$, *then* showing that with those choices, $a\neq c$ and $b\neq d$, yet $(a,b)=(c,d)$.